# prevent event on symfony submitted form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, confirm

I want that user check the input data's form in a confim dialog after submit. So I write this:

```
$('form[name="my_form"]').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).href;

    confirm("are you sure?", function () {
        window.location = href;
    });
});
```

but if I choose OK on confirm the browser redirect to undefined. Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to redirect the user via window.location, it would have the same effect as if your user would have clicked on a link (no form submitted, and you would loose the form data).

Try something like this maybe?

```
$('form[name="my_form"]').submit(function(event) {
     return confirm("are you sure?");
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/FloSchieldBobby/ysp01vna/

Comment: if i don't prevent event the form go on to his action

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me on Chrome 60 currently...

Comment: yes, form me not work on crhrome in linux mint. The confirm is open but the form go however.

Comment: What about the edited solution?

Comment: this not redirect never, neither when i confirm the dialog.

Comment: this works for you?

Comment: Yep, both work on Chrome 60 for OS X

Comment: I'll try it on Linux after lunch

Comment: thanks, i don't understand why this. I'm using symfony form backend and twig for frontend.

Comment: It's not related to symfony or back-end actually, it's just JavaScript :)

Comment: I've updated the answer with a demo link, it actually works for me on Firefox 54 and Chromium 59 for Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) ;
Could you test the demo link in your environment and see if it still doesn't work for you?